# Smartsheet-API links out data is blank

Tags: smartsheet-api

When I attempt to extract the links out from a cell, I get "null" for cells that do not have links and something like this for the ones that do:

{"sheetId": null, "rowId": null, "columnId": null, "sheetName": null, "status": null}

This is the same regardless of if the cell links out to a single destination or multiple ones.

I retrieve a row and then run through each cell in the row.

The entire cell's JSON looks like this (with column ID masked)

{"columnId": XXXXXX, "strict": true, "formula": null, "displayValue": "Yellow", "conditionalFormat": null, "linksOutToCells": {"sheetId": null, "rowId": null, "columnId": null, "sheetName": null, "status": null}, "value": "Yellow", "columnType": null, "linkInFromCell": null, "format": null, "hyperlink": null}

Is there another way to retrieve the outgoing link information?

I'm using Python and SDK 2.0.10

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linksOutToCells should be deserialized as a list. This change will be made in a soon to be released pip. If you need to pick this up before the updated pip, here is a link to the github commit:

https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/commit/bf41069fd17cfc950f1b7eb25338be3805eda084

Comment: Thanks. I updated my version of cell.py, updated my code for the TypedList and testing is OK.

Answer (score 0):

It appears we have a bug in deserialization. More shortly...